# Transaction does not retrieve on time data

Tags: oracle, jpa, jakarta-ee, transactions, persistence

I have a project with many services. I'm using pure jpa with jersey in my project.

I use entityManager, entityTransaction and entityManagerFactory in this way: for each service I get an EntityManager from DBManager.getEntityManager() and get and entityTransaction from its entityManager

```
public class DBManager {
    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("projectDataSource").getEntityManager();
}
```

In each method that need transaction, first I check `transaction != null` and transaction is not active

Then I begin the transaction.

I evict cache and after all of this I do my job: in this example I get all active users from database, and my service that returns users list to client.

One of my services is : `@getUsersService`

```
public class GetUsersServiceImpl {

private static EntityManager entiyManager = DBManager.getEntityManager();
private static EntityTransaction entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();

public List<User> getUsers()
    if (transaction != null && !transaction.isActive())
        transaction.begin()

    entityManager.getEntityMangerFactory().getCache().evictAll();

    return entityManger.createQuery("SELECT u FROM USER u WHERE u.isActive = true").getResultList();
}
```

This code works but not always!

I have another service that changes the users; this user also works and changes user data in database, but after calling change service when I call getUsers service, it retrieves old database data

Why does this happen?

Is it correct the way I use entityManager and entityTransaction ...

Comment: why not debug it, look in the log of your JPA provider, and then you see where it is getting the data from ... cache or database.

Comment: @BillyFrost when i debug my app in my system it works fine but when i deploy my war file in server this error occurs.

Comment: but the problem is the query retrieves old data that currently not exists in database

Comment: If the query goes to the database then it does NOT retrieve data that doesn't exist in the DATABASE. So I say to you one last time, DEBUG your application and look in the log at where it is getting the data from.

Comment: @BillyFrost another question :D is it true that i use static entityManger on each of my services or not

Comment: @BillyFrost if i use non-static entity manger and close it at end of catch block what ?